# Qgis docking plugin - python

Tags: qgis, python

I need to create a dock plugin for QGIS using QT designer and Python.
I've created a basic plugin in "plugin builder". Then I've changed the .ui so now I dont have standard QDialog box but a QDockWidget.
So now i have "plugin_module_dialog.py" that looks like that:

```
import os

from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic

FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'testing_module_dialog_base.ui'))

class testing_classDialog(QtGui.QDockWidget, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(testing_classDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
```

and "plugin_module.py" like that:

```
class testing_class:

    def __init__(self, iface):

        self.iface = iface

        path = os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( __file__ ) )
        self.dock = uic.loadUi( os.path.join( path, "plugin_module_dialog_base.ui" ) )
        self.iface.addDockWidget( Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.dock )
        ...
```

Now when i run that plugin i get:

```
AttributeError: 'plugin_classDialog' object has no attribute 'exec_'
```

And the plugin window pops up normally. Not docked. 
I am new to that. Please explain me what should I do to get working dock plugin.

Comment: What I would do is to have have a look at a sample plugin that relies on a DockWidget. Take for example the lrs plugin: https://github.com/blazek/lrs/blob/master/lrs/lrsplugin.py

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem yesterday. Step 1: Build a GUI creator something like (ui2py) to make a py file out of your ui.

```
import os
os.system("C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/pyuic4.bat -x testing_module_dialog_base.ui -o testing_module_dialog_base.py")
print("Done!")
```

Step 2: Your plugin_module_dialog.py will look like that..

```
import os
from PyQt4.Core import Ot
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic

from testing_module_dialog_base.py import Testing_Module_Dialog_Base #or whatever the class is called in it

class testing_classDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor."""
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, None, Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.ui = Testing_Module_Dialog_Base()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.iface = iface
```

Install PyQt4 in order to do the first step.

Step3 (optional): 
I strongly recommend you building a "GUI-Runner". It would look like this..

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

from testing_classDialog.py import testing_classDialog

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = testing_classDialog(None)
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Have fun.